# When to flag question as duplicate?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

> Possible duplicate:
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165538/whats-the-rule-in-considering-duplicated-questions

I have recently become more involved in modding actions on StackOverflow and am still learning what reason fits what.

I flagged this question: [Set caret after creating new element in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536833/set-caret-after-creating-new-element-in-contenteditable-div) 
as a duplicate of [How to set caret(cursor) position in contenteditable element (div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249095/how-to-set-caretcursor-position-in-contenteditable-element-div).

It's not *exactly* the same question but the answer can be trivially inferred from the chosen answer.

Did I appropriately flagged the question as a duplicate? and if not What should I consider before I flag a duplicate.

Comment: What is your question here? Are you asking if you appropriately flagged the question as a duplicate?

Comment: That's really why it takes several people to actually close a question as a duplicate, you think it's a dupe so mark it as such and if enough people agree then it'll be closed as a duplicate. If enough people *don't* agree then it won't. It's democratic and all that.

Comment: @Bart yes this is my question. And what should I change next time I flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it:

- If it's the same problem, just different look, it is a duplicate.
- If it's another problem that happens to have similar answers, or even practically identical ones, it is not a duplicate - but it is worth to comment with link to an answered question or take best existing answer to old question and tailor it to the new question. Post it with link to original answer, of course.